# Angular mouseover minimum reaction time

Tags: angular, angular-material, mouseover

I have associated mouseover with a button but interestingly it is detected only if mouse pointer moves at relatively slower speed compared to quick jerk to mouse to move pointer from one corner to another.
So, when pointer speed is too high, no mouse over is detected.
So, can this reaction time be decreased?